# Oracle query to find listener protocol

Tags: sql, oracle, tcp, protocols, ipc

Is it possible to find the current listener protocol (`ipc` or `tcp`) through query? My requirement is to find if the listener is using `tcp` then perform set of operations in `pl/sql` otherwise perform set of other operations. Tried to find the details on Oracle Docs as well as in other DBA related forums, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Access to file `listener.ora` (e.g. with external table) and check the line `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))`. But the DBA's wouldn't be delighted from this scenario...

Comment: `v$session_connect_info` is probably the best place to start. You could check the `network_service_banner` content, or maybe the `client_driver`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the info, the query on `client_driver` returns `SQL*PLUS`, the substr query on `network_service_banner` returns `Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter`.

Comment: `Oracle Bequeath` means it's a local connection (so no TCP)